# Is it possible to add a view model on the _layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

The scenario is that I want to populate the navigation bar, the menu, with Mvc.Sitemap.

How should I achieve this?

It feels strange to add a View Model onto the layout page. And that may cause a view to have more than one View Models.

can any one help? Thank you.

Update: ----------
I have Home/_Menu as a partial view which uses MenuViewModel. But how can I include that View in _layout?

I cannot simply use `@Html.Partial("_Menu")` inside my `_Layout.cshtml` because I need to specify the controller and action where the view model is built. What is the correct way to do this?

And if I do `@Html.RenderAction("_Menu", "Home")`, I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error on the Model.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have a model in your Layout, because then every view that you call from there by default will have this model. Instead you should create a Menu view with the model, and when you call it pass a new MenuModel to it as a model.

Edit: 
You can have a class that will pull data out of where you store your menu values. Then you call your partial like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_Menu_", menuobject.Root)
```

And the class:

```
partial class menuobject
{
    public static menuobject Root
    {
        // MenuRoots are all roots that have ID -1 - which will be the root
        return MenuRoots.Single(x => x.Something == "Topnavi"); // this will return the root above all your menus
    }
}
```

Than in your view you go foreach() on each level of menus to populate them.

Comment: I have been trying to do this. Please see the updated question. Thank you.

Comment: Updated the question. I hope it helps.